# Optimize the printing of the results of a recursive function

Tags: c++

I have the following function, used to print shortest path from source to j

```
void printPath(int parent[], int j) {
    
    // base case, i.e. if j is the source
    if (parent[j] == -1)
        return;

    printPath(parent, parent[j]);

    cout << j+1 << "-";
}
```

It prints results like `1-3-5-6-`. How can I change the code to not print the last `-`? The goal is to get the result `1-3-5-6`.

Comment: Usually you'd write `cout << j+1 << "-";` and avoid printing the first `"-"`, which is much easier (bool flag).

Comment: Not sure I understand, what should I change?

Comment: Pretty sure it was supposed to be `cout << "-" << j+1;`.

Comment: Also note: that there is no guarantee `parent[j]` is within the bounds of the `parent` array. E.g. `int parent[] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 };` will invoke *Undefined Behavior* when the recursive call `printPath (parent, 8);` is reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
void printPath(int parent[], int j) {
    
    // base case, i.e. if j is the source
    if (parent[j] == -1)
        return;

    printPath(parent, parent[j]);

    if (parent[parent[j]] != -1)
        cout << "-";
    cout << j+1;
}
```